# How do I open a JSON file and extract some extra data and saved them to variables?

Tags: python, json, file, variables

I want to open this JSON file and extract everything that's in quotes in this JSON example and store them in their own individual variables to be used somewhere else. How do I do that?

```
{
  "class":
  {
        "student1":
        {
            "studentID": "20345",
            "Campbell":
            {
                "Sims": {"grade": "5", "class_size": "30"}
            }
        },
        "student2":
        {
            "studentID": "20022",
            "Williams":
            {
                "Johnson": {"grade": "3", "class_size": "25"}
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both key and value are iterated, and the target value is extracted from the observed JSON structure

```
import json

with open("test.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

info_list = []
for k, v in data["class"].items():
    name = k
    id_, other_name, grade = "", "", ""
    for x, y in v.items():
        if "studentID" == x:
            id_ = y
        else:
            other_name = x
            grade = list(y.values())[0]["grade"]
    info_list.append((name, "studentID", id_, other_name, "grade", grade))
print(info_list)
```

OutPut

```
[('student1', 'studentID', '20345', 'Campbell', 'grade', '5'), ('student2', 'studentID', '20022', 'Williams', 'grade', '3')]
```

Comment: How do I  saved them in individual variables

Comment: @Jtigg I can't figure out which values you want to put in a individual variable. Isn't this JSON data in a separate 'result'?

Comment: I want to grab 'student1', 'studentID',  '20345', 'Campbell', 'grade' and '5'

Comment: @Jtigg  Just try this

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

file = open('data.json')

data = json.load(file)

individual_info = []

for i in data['class']:
    individual_data.append(i)
  
f.close()
```

in this code you are storing the data from the file temporarily in the variable i, then appending it to your list `individual_data`, which will persist after the loop concludes. What you do with that data, and how you access particular pieces, depends on the function of your program.